# Cant connect an ESXI host behind an ubuntu NATusing Vsphere

Tags: vmware, iptables, port-forwarding, nat

I have 2 NIC's on ubuntu ;

eth1 (pci-e based net. card) > WAN (router) and
eth0 (onboard) > server (onboard) (no cross cable)

so what I want is to access both ubuntu (vnc and ssh) and esxi server (vnc and ssh into one machine and probably ftp too)

I have eth0 connection to esxi from 10.8.16 sub and local router from 192.168.2 sub

I have setten up the nat using
https://www.howtoforge.com/nat-gateway-iptables-port-forwarding-dns-and-dhcp-setup-ubuntu-8.10-server

and used the following commands

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 902 -j DNAT --to 10.8.16.2:902

/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth1 --dport 902 -j DNAT --to 10.8.16.2:902
```

when I try to connect 10.8.16.2 via browser (from ubuntu) it displays esxi's default page correctly

also when I try to detect the port from ubuntu using nmap

```
nmap -A 10.8.16.2 -p 902
Nmap scan report for 10.8.16.2
Host is up (0.00064s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE         VERSION
902/tcp open  ssl/vmware-auth VMware Authentication Daemon 1.10 (Uses VNC, SOAP)
```

which Im assuming it sees the auth daemon

when executed from outside network (a pc in the 192.168.2 sub)

```
    nmap -A 192.168.2.193 -p 902
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.193
    Host is up (0.000096s latency).
    PORT    STATE SERVICE         VERSION
    902/tcp open  ssl/vmware-auth VMware Authentication Daemon 1.10 (Uses VNC, SOAP)
    MAC Address: 00:10:18:1A:FA:09 (Broadcom)
    Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
    Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 2.4.21 (91%), Linux 2.6.24 (88%), DD-WRT (Linux 2.4.35s) (87%), VMware ESXi 4.1 (87%), Linux 2.6.24 - 2.6.25 (87%), Asus RT-N10 router or AXIS 211A Network Camera (Linux 2.6) (87%), Linux 2.6.18 (87%), AXIS 211A Network Camera (Linux 2.6.20) (87%), Linux 2.6.16 (86%), VMware ESXi 5.5 (86%)
    No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).
    Network Distance: 1 hop

    TRACEROUTE
    HOP RTT     ADDRESS
    1   0.10 ms 192.168.2.193

    OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.78 seconds
```

as you can see it also sees the esxi login service
so why I cant connect to my esxi server via vsphere ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who were wondering, I managed to find a solution while typing the question. I just checked if there were other ports to forward aswell and bingo.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012382#ESXi5x

```
ESXi 5.x    427 UDP VI / vSphere Client ESXi/ESX Host   CIM Service Location Protocol (SLP)
ESXi 5.x    443 TCP VI / vSphere Client ESXi/ESX Host   VI / vSphere Client to ESXi/ESX Host management connection
```

I forgot to portforward them. Now I can connect to it easily.